# iOS - removeDeliveredNotifications, removeAllDeliveredNotifications for critical alerts

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to remove delivered critical alerts using `removeAllDeliveredNotifications()` and `removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers identifiers: [String])` but this simply doesn't work (iOS 14.7.1).

It's working properly for regular (non-critical) notifications.

Is this a feature or a bug? Maybe someone has a workaround for this?